# URL doesnot show utm parameters.

Tags: c#, xamarin, uri, utm-tracking

I have a piece of code in which i am passing the utm parameters along with url to the Device.OpenUri but it is hiding the utm parameter when i open the link in browser. I want the utm parameters displayed along with the URL. I dont know how do i do it? Please help
Post.NewsItem.Url contains the URL and i am adding utm parameter to it.

```
void MoreInfoButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(viewModel.MoreInfoUrl));
        Logger.Instance.log("More Info button clicked", LogLevel.DEBUG);
    }

if (post.NewsItem.Url.Contains('?')){
MoreInfoUrl = post.NewsItem.Url + "&utm_source=dorffunk&utm_medium=app";
}else
{
MoreInfoUrl = post.NewsItem.Url + "?utm_source=dorffunk&utm_medium=app";}
```

Comment: If you put a log line before the line that says "Device.OpenUri" and send the contents of viewModel.MoreInfoUrl o the log method, what do you see in the log? do you see in the log the full url you are expecting?

Comment: It is showing nothing because logged is just logging the info about button clicked not the URL i guess

Comment: This is working Device.OpenUri(new Uri(viewModel.MoreInfoUrl + "?utm_source=dorffunk&utm_medium=app"));   but this is not ---- MoreInfoUrl = post.NewsItem.Url + "&utm_source=dorffunk&utm_medium=app";

Comment: What I meant was to add: Logger.Instance.log("The url " + viewModel.MoreInfoUrl, LogLevel.DEBUG);  before the call to OpenUri. THat way you know for sure if MoreInfoUrl is actually being updated from the other code. Speaking of other code, what triggers the other lines where you are actually updating the viewModel? do you know for sure they are being hit? did you try adding a breakpoint to see if the debugger hits those lines?

Comment: There was another bug in the code and because of which it was not working. I firgured it out and now it is working fine. Thanks alot for all the help and support.

Comment: Sounds good! you probably want to put that in the answer box, that way the question is shown as "answered".

Answer (score 0):

There was another bug in the code and because of which it was not working. I firgured it out and now it is working fine. Thanks alot for all the help and support.